# Issue in Sql between date with where conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the count of orders between two date for a particular shop.

Here is what i have tried.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $orders WHERE Ordereddate >= $from AND Ordereddate <= $to
```

While i improve the query by adding Where shop id , i am getting error. What is the mistake i am doing ?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $orders WHERE Ordereddate >= $from AND Ordereddate <= $to AND Shopid='100'
```

Comment: Can you show the error message please?

Comment: Can you post the table structure of the `orders` table?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $orders WHERE (Ordereddate >= $from AND Ordereddate <= $to) AND Shopid='100'

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: Just an observation, but you might try back ticks around your fields and single quotes around your date vars

Comment: Actually i am not getting any error, but i am just getting 0 as result

Answer (score 0):

Try this .... use brackets between the dates...

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $orders WHERE (`Ordereddate` >= $from AND `Ordereddate` <= $to) AND Shopid='100';
```

Or if you are facing and error, please post that as well...